# can a pdf random variable dip negative

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Can there be a valid pdf/cdf for a random variable where the pdf dips negative in the domain?

For example:

$$ f(x) = 2x - x^3, for (0,5/2) $$

this function dips negative near 2, and is negative between 2 and 5/2

Comment: No, a probability density function (pdf) must be non-negative over the entire domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one job of a density function is to satisfy the relationship
$$\mathbb P(X \in [a, b]) = \int_a^b f(x) \, \textrm d x$$
for any interval $[a, b]$.

But in this case, if $[a, b] = [2, 5/2]$, then this integral will be negative. That's a bad thing, and this is why no density function can ever be negative on an interval.

Comment: maybe add an `= 1` at the end of that eq

Comment: We'd want a trailing `= 1` if (and only if) the interval is $(-\infty, \infty)$; the statement is more general than that.